# .Net 2.0 the received tiff file images are inverted

Tags: javascript, .net, xmlhttprequest, tiff, msxml

A question which involves mainly web I believe.

I create a tiff file from a scanner and save it on the hard drive (all is perfect till here).
My next step is to upload the file to the server in this manner (existing JavaScript code):

```
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Upload the scanned document to the server and them save it to CM.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    function SaveToDriveU()
    {
    try
    {
    document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
    objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    objStream.Mode = 3; // read write
    objStream.Type = 1; // adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open();
    objStream.LoadFromFile(strScanedFileName);

    //var streamToSend = objStream.Read(objStream.Size);
    try
    {
    streamToSend = objStream.Read(-1);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
    alert(err.message);
    }

    window.setTimeout("SendXmlHttpRequest()",1000);

    //objStream.Close();

    }
    catch (err)
    {
    alert("???? ????? ?????? ????? ???????:" + err.message);
    }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Send XmlHttpRequest
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    function SendXmlHttpRequest()
    {
    try
    {
    objXMLhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");

    // Upload the scanned document via XMLHTTP request.
    objXMLhttp.Open("POST", "Uploader.aspx", true);
    objXMLhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", objStream.Size);
    objXMLhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","image/tiff");

    objXMLhttp.onreadystatechange = function() // Check the upload request status.
    {
    if(objXMLhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
    if(objXMLhttp.responseText.substr(0,2) == "OK")
    {
    document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    mstrNewDocID = objXMLhttp.responseText.substr(2,(objXMLhttp.responseText.length - 2));

    document.all.NewDocID.value = mstrNewDocID;
    Form1.submit();
    }
    else
    {
    // If the upload failed, display the error message to the user.
    var strPageUrl = "RunScanner/FailedScanMsg.aspx?ErrorMsg=????? ????? ????? ?????";
    location.replace(strPageUrl);
    }
    // Delete the local scanned document from the disk.
    DeleteScanedFile();
    }
    }

    objXMLhttp.send(streamToSend);
    }
    catch (err)
    {
    alert("???? ????? ?????? ????? ???????:" + err.message);
    }
    }
```

Now question splits to two directions:

1. Hosted .Net 4.0 all is perfect.
2. Hosted .Net 2.0 the received tiff file images are inverted (meaning if the image was black on white it will now be white on black)

   The hosted on .Net 2.0 is because of old code that still needs to be supported at clients and cannot be upgraded easily.

The above is the only difference I could tell.

Anyone has any better idea on this?

Why is this happening? How to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: I still do not know how it relates to .Net 2.0 but it seems to be an issue of how I created the TIFF file, the compression I used.
I tried a few which didn`t work:
CCITTFAX4,CCITTFAX3,CCITTRLEW,ADOBE_DEFLATE,DEFLATE,DCS,IT8BL,IT8CTPAD,IT8LW,JBIG,SGILOG24,THUNDERSCAN,SGILOG,PIXARLOG,PIXARFILM
and last I managed to get it to work with:
PACKBITS
I would love to know still how it is affected by the .Net 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to try other compression methods. I think it has something to do with the binary transfer of the data